# Apache mod_authn_dba with Oracle on Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, oracle

How can I configure Apache to authenticate against Oracle dbms?

According to this link [Oracle database is natively supported. No additional software required.](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/connect-mod_dbd-with-databases/)

Loading those modules:

```
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
```

and configuring the directory (and `mod_dbd params`):

```
# mod_dbd configuration
DBDriver oracle
DBDParams "server=XXX:1521 dbname=orcl user=IDM_ANTIVIR password=xxx"

DBDMin  4
DBDKeep 8
DBDMax  20
DBDExptime 300

<Directory F:/Projects/>
  # core authentication and mod_auth_basic configuration
  # for mod_authn_dbd
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My Server"
  AuthBasicProvider dbd

  # core authorization configuration
  Require valid-user

  # mod_authn_dbd SQL query to authenticate a user
  AuthDBDUserPWQuery \
    "SELECT PASSWORD FROM IDM.VW_ANTIVIR_PASSWORD WHERE LDAPUID = %s;"
</Directory>
```

Results in the following error:

```
[Mon Jul 28 17:28:55 2014] [error] (OS 126)Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.  : DBD: mod_dbd not compatible with APR in get_driver
[Mon Jul 28 17:28:55 2014] [error] (OS 126)Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.  : DBD: failed to initialise
```

`apr_dbd_oracle-1.dll` exists in the Apache bin directory.

Whats missing? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch to me: "mod_dbd not compatible with APR in get_driver".

Comment: Problem occurs on different wamp instances (with different versions), so I do not think that this is a version problem (all out of the box)